# react-router redirect not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I am using latest version of create-react-app, mobx-react, material-ui and react-router . When I tried to redirect to other component using `Redirect` component it doesn't work. Then I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42898856/2566671) , still the problem persists.

my codes:

```
//App.js
// other imports
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Cart from "./stores/Cart";


const cart_counter = new Cart();


class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <React.Fragment>
                    <Route path="/" exact render={(props) => <Index {...props} cart_counter={cart_counter}/>} />
                    <Route path="/product/:slug" render={(props) => <Product {...props} cart_counter={cart_counter}/>} />
                </React.Fragment>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;


// Index.js
class IndexComponent extends React.Component {
   moveToProduct(slug) {
        return <Redirect push to={"/product/" + slug} />;
    }
   render() {
        return (
          <Grid item xs={6} sm={3} key={product.id}>
                    <Card onClick={() => {this.moveToProduct(product.slug)}}>
           </Grid>
       )}
   const Index = withRouter(observer(IndexComponent));

   export default withStyles(styles)(Index);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Redirect` must be rendered but right now you just return it from your click. You have to set a defined state on your click which will conditionally render your `Redirect`. A boolean will do the job.

Comment: as an alternative, you can use `this.props.history.push(`/push/${slug}`)` to redirect.