# When using Redirect, my state won't update so I never redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

### Background

I have a react/redux project with a form. I'd like it to redirect to another page on my site after the form is submitted.

In researching the issue here, I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738249/react-router-v4-redirecting-on-form-submit) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53170754/redirect-after-submit-in-react) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42875949/react-router-v4-redirect-not-working), plus other solutions on github and none quite work. Most solutions dealt with a state change, some used withRouter. I'm not sure what I am missing.

### Code

Here is my form.

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {addProgram} from '../../actions/addProgram'
import {Form} from 'semantic-ui-react'
import {Redirect} from 'react-router'

class ProgramInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      network: '',
      image: '',
      fireRedirect: false
    }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
  }

  handleRedirect = event => {
    this.setState({
      fireRedirect: true
    })
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()

    this.props.addProgram(this.state)


    this.setState({
      name: '',
      network: '',
      image: '',
      fireRedirect: ''
    })
  }

  render(){
    const fireRedirect = this.state.fireRedirect

        if (fireRedirect === true) {
          return <Redirect to='/programs' /> }

    return(
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <h2>Create a New Show</h2>
                <Form.Input
                  fluid
                  label='Name'
                  name='name'
                  value={this.state.name}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  width={6} />
                <Form.Input
                  fluid
                  name='network'
                  label='Network'
                  value={this.state.network}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  width={6} />
                <Form.Input
                  fluid
                  name='image'
                  label='Image Link'
                  value={this.state.image}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  width={8} />
                <Form.Button>Submit</Form.Button>
            </Form>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(null, {addProgram})(ProgramInput)
```

### Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Hi Koberlander, just wrote you a solution, let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason your current code fails is because `handleRedirect` is never called. It's unnecessary to have this in it's own method, but if that's what you prefer, then just call `handleRedirect()` from `handleChange`.

Answer (score 1):

You never call your `handleRedirect` function to update the `fireRedirect` state. Try modifying your `handleSubmit` function, and use `fireRedirect` in the setState call-back. This will give the visual effect of redirecting to `"/programs"` after submitting and clearing the form.

```
  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()

    this.props.addProgram(this.state)


    this.setState({
      name: '',
      network: '',
      image: '',
      fireRedirect: ''
    }, () => this.handleRedirect())
  }
```

Comment: This got my <Redirect> to fire but now I'm getting an error when it tries to re-render all of my programs. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null`. It's being called in my .map on line 20 of [this file](https://github.com/koberlander/tv-list-frontend/blob/master/src/components/programs/Programs.js)